# Using func while retriving date from database

Tags: c#

I have a method that retrieves timestamp intervals from db and it looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetCurrentsFlagTimestampPoints(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return currentsRepository.GetTimestampPoints(startDate, endDate).Select(timestamp => new DateTime(timestamp.Year, timestamp.Month, timestamp.Day)).Distinct();
}
```

But now I want to use it more in a more generic way, so i want to pass `Func<>` that will describe resulting date format so once I want to return

```
new DateTime(timestamp.Year, timestamp.Month, timestamp.Day)
```

and once

```
new DateTime(timestamp.Year, timestamp.Month, timestamp.Day, timestamp.Hour)
```

I could do that using overloads of some sort but that would change the already existing structure of some methods.

I don't know how to tackle this, is it possible??

Edit:

It works nice without Expression so:

```
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetCurrentsFlagTimestampPoints(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, Func<DateTime, DateTime> dateTimeExpr)
    {
        return currentsRepository.GetTimestampPoints(startDate, endDate).Select(dateTimeExpr).Distinct();
    }
```

Comment: You should try `Expression<Func<>>`.

Comment: I'm not clear what your `Func<>` would do or why? Can you try and explain more clearly?

Comment: This question as it stands is incomplete. We don't know whether `GetTimestampPoints` returns `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` to tell you whether to use `Expression<Func<>>` or just `Func<>`. If it returns `IEnumerable<T>`, the method is completely wrong already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `Expression<Func<DateTime,DateTime>>` as a param:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetCurrentsFlagTimestampPoints(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, Expression<Func<DateTime, DateTime>> dateTimeExpr)
{
    return currentsRepository.GetTimestampPoints(startDate, endDate).Select(dateTimeExpr).Distinct();
}

Expression<Func<DateTime, Datetime>> f1 = timestamp => new DateTime(timestamp.Year, timestamp.Month, timestamp.Day);

Expression<Func<DateTime, Datetime>> f1 = timestamp => new DateTime(timestamp.Year, timestamp.Month, timestamp.Day, timestamp.Hour);

GetCurrentsFlagTimestampPoints(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, f1); // or f2
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `Expression<Func<DateTime, DateTime>>` since the OP says "from database" which is likely Entity Framework? If `GetTimestampPoints` returns `IQueryable`, of course, which we don't know

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - I've missed that..I guess you are right, however, it depends on the return type of the GetTimestampPoints method.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it depends on what `GetTimestampPoints` returns. It would be wrong if it returned `IEnumerable` though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - Didn't see the edit. Anyway, my answer supports the IQueryable approach. If the result is IEnumerable, simply drop the Expression wrap.